# JavaScripting in Mirth - Ignore DG1 segments Until Condition Is Met

Tags: javascript, mirth

```
DG1|1||Z3800^Single liveborn infant, delivered vaginally^I10|||A|||||||||||||||||||||
DG1|2||Z23^Encounter for immunization^I10|||S||||||||||||||||||||E|
DG1|3||A3800^Single liveborn infant, delivered vaginally^I10|||P||||||||||||||||||||E|
DG1|4||B3800^Single liveborn infant, delivered vaginally^I10|||S||||||||||||||||||||E|
```

The above message sample is formatted in a way that I only want to start reading the values of DG1 when DG1.6 = P.  And then read in the DG1 segments after when DG1.6 is P.  In the above example, I want to ignore DG1|1, DG1|2 and then only store the values of DG1|3 and DG1|4.  I tried using localeCompare but soon realized that doesn't look like what I can easily use.  I also tried assigning A, P, and S numerical values to compare which I think will work (essentially adding |1|+1 when A = 1, |2|+2 when S = 2, etc.  But I feel like I'm complicating it.

DG1 is a dynamic set in HL7 so it can be of any length.

Here's my current code set that will ignore DG1 segment when DG1.6 is "A".

```
var dxXML = '';
var dg1Count = msg['DG1'].length();

for (var i = 0; i < dg1Count; i++) {
    var dx;
    var poa;

    if (msg['DG1'][i] != undefined) {
        if (msg['DG1'][i]['DG1.6']['DG1.6.1'].toString() == 'A' || msg['DG1'][i]['DG1.6']['DG1.6.1'].toString() == 'ADMITTING') {
            //format: <Dx Code="${dx0}" POA="${poa0}" Pos="1"/>
            dx = '';
            poa = '';
            if (dxXML != '') {
                dxXML = dxXML + '\n<Dx Code="' + dx + '" POA="' + poa + '" Pos="' + i + '"/>';
            } else {
                dxXML = '<Dx Code="' + dx + '" POA="' + poa + '" Pos="' + i + '"/>';
            }
        }
        //normal dx. the first non-blank dx will be imported as PDX. This means the i can be any integer.
        else {
            dx = msg['DG1'][i]['DG1.3']['DG1.3.1'].toString();
            poa = msg['DG1'][i]['DG1.26']['DG1.26.1'].toString();
            
            if (dx == '') continue;
            if (poa == 'E' || poa == '') {
                poa = '1'; 
            }       
    
            if (dxXML != '') {              
                dxXML = dxXML + '\n<Dx Code="' + dx + '" POA="' + poa + '" Pos="' + i + '"/>';
            } else {                    
                dxXML = '<Dx Code="' + dx + '" POA="' + poa + '" Pos="' + i + '"/>';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //do nothing to not add the blank ones.
    }
}
$c('DX_DOM', dxXML);
```

Any guidance on how to accomplish this will be appreciated.

Comment: You say you only want to perform your action when DG1.6=P, which is not true for DG1|4, so why do you want to keep it? Just trying to better understand the question.

Comment: Hi Gavin.  In the above example, I'd ignore DG1|1-2 and read in DG1|3-4.  DG1.6 = P would be the indicator to start reading in DG1 segments (starting with DG1.6 = P and then any DG1 segments afterwards).  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I was able to figure it out after a good night's sleep.
```
for (var i = 0; i < dg1Count; i++) {
 var dx;
 var poa;

 if (msg['DG1'][i] != undefined) {
  if (msg['DG1'][i]['DG1.6']['DG1.6.1'].toString() == 'P') {
   var pdx = i;
   logger.info("pdx: "+pdx);
  }
 }
}
```